# Use Google Colab to complete the objectives for Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Remove line breaks, single quotes, double quotes, and email addresses. Tokenize each string. Convert each tweet to a list of cleaned words and add to a master list. Print out the first five cleaned tweets in the list.

```
import pandas as pd

# Step 1: Import the data file
data_file = 'tw_tweets_users_media_places-Lindiwe_Vinson_Garrett.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_file)

# Step 2: Removing newline 
lst=['This\n','is\n','Python\n','Pool\n']
rep = []
for x in lst:
    rep.append(x.replace("\n", ""))

# Step 3: Removing Quotes 
x = "'Welcome to Java2blog'"
y = x.strip(" \' ")

# Step 4: Removing Emails
HAVE A MAJOR ISSUE WITH THIS STEP

# Step 5: Tokenize each string
HAVE A MAJOR ISSUE WITH THIS STEP

# Step 6: Tokenize each string
Convert each tweet to a list of cleaned words and add to a master list

# Step 7: Print the first five records
print(df.head(5))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.